# Can a Sitecore Lucene index be programmatically built?

Tags: indexing, lucene, sitecore

When using Lucene indexing in Sitecore, is it possible to add items to an index based on the content of an item?  Indexes can be built based on template id but I would like to add additional criteria to filter items before they are added to the index.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you mean. The headline seems different than the body?

Anyways, from the actual question, I understand that you'd like to add items only if a given criteria is meet? It could for instance be - only add items that are based on template X.

As far as I know, the responsibility for getting data for the index lies with the ItemCrawler. The standard ItemCrawlers are based on paths (e.g. everything under /Sitecore/home is indexed). I am thinking you could make your own ItemCrawler and use that in your index instead.

Here are some examples of a custom item crawlers:

http://mityasctech.blogspot.com/2016/10/create-custom-sitecore-search-crawler.html
http://mrstevenzhao.blogspot.com/2014/04/sitecore-custom-item-crawler.html

I hope this can help you.

Comment: i saw these however no example was provided.  From what i understand, Lucene indexes are built using a config file and only template id can be used to populate indexes.  I was hoping to write a program that populated an index using the Lucene API (if one exists).  I need more that template id criteria.  I need item content filters.
The second link provided a little sample however the context of the item was not provided and i don't know if it's available.

Comment: Correct, Lucene indexes are built, in Sitecore, based on config files where you specify either which fields should be included or index everything and then exclude field. 

The ItemCrawlers is what is responsible for getting the items to the index. The standard crawler uses a path and recursively takes everything under that path. However, with a custom one, you should be able to select items based on your own criteria.